# Component did update works only after second click

Tags: reactjs

My code adds a new item in the firebase databse when i click a button, then i want the list of objects in my page to automatically update, because i don't want to manualy reload the page. So i came up with this code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groups: [],
      code:'',
      name:'',
      update:true
    }
  }

  async fetchGroups (id){
    fetchGroupsFirebase(id).then((res) => {this.setState({groups:res})})
  };

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
    if(this.state.update !== prevState.update){
      await this.fetchGroups(this.props.user.id);
    }
  }

handleCreateSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const{name} = this.state;
    try{
        firestore.collection("groups").add({
            title:name,
            owner:this.props.user.id
        })
        .then((ref) => {
            firestore.collection("user-group").add({
                idGroup:ref.id,
                idUser:this.props.user.id
            });
        });
        this.setState({update: !this.state.update});
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
```

What i was thinking, after i add the new item in firebase, i change the state.update variable, which triggers componentDidUpdate, which calls the new fetching.

I tried calling the fetchGroups function in the submit function, but that didn't work either.

What am i doing wrong and how could i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComponentDidUpdate will not be called on initial render. You can either additionally use `componentDidMount` or replace the class component with a functional component and use the hook `useEffect` instead.

Regarding useEffect, this could be your effect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      await this.fetchGroups(this.props.user.id);
  }, [update]);
```

Since you can't use useEffect in class components so you would need to rewrite it as functional and replace your this.state with useState.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, because initially my list of groups is populated with the correct groups, only i want it to updated only when i click on a submit button, but maybe the useEffect could help, do you have any example?

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer. Does this work for you?